# ng repeat http request execution time increasing exponentially AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat directive which iterates over a collection of objects. I would like to make an http request for every item fetched to get some extra information.

view.html

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id" ng-init="getItemDetails(item)">
</li>
```

mycontroller.js

```
$scope.getItemDetails = function (item) {
    itemRepository.getItem(item.id, AppConfig.constants.itemFields).then(function (result) {
        item.totalFilesCount = result.data.totalFilesCount;
    });
};
```

The problem works as expected but each http request execution time is increasing exponentially. Below is attached the Chrome Network requests snapshot. The penultimate column represents execution time.[image]

Is there a way to make those http requestes asynchronously?

Comment: I think it's better to make a for loop for `items` array, instead of putting a function call on an `ng-repeat` body. It has a watcher on it, so your functions will be called every time `items` changes. With a for loop you can collect your results into a single array with `$q.all(promises).then((res)=>{$scope.array = res;})`

Comment: Those http requests are already async. There are some browser limitations for http requests - e.g. number of opened requests to one domain.  You need to reconsider your app design for sure. It is very akward to have number of requests ~ number of items. Beside this using ng-init like you do is bad way to go.